# How to reuse yielded value later in the test

Tags: javascript, global-variables, ui-automation, cypress, e2e-testing

Context: I have an element with innerText in Page1 and another element with innerText on Page 2. And I need to compare these two values in Page 3. So I need to find a way to save these values in a variable globally so that they can be used later.

Things I tried:

**Trial 1:** Didn't work as page1value scope is limited to the cy.get()

```
  cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
      const page1value = text
  })
```

**Trial 2:** Didn't work as whenever I try to print the value outside, it comes as undefined or the value with which it was initialized it with.

```
it('TC Name', () => {

    let page1value,
        cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
            page1value = text
        })

    cy.log(page1value) //comes as undefined

})
```

**Trial 3:** Using .as() as well its coming as undefined.

```
let page1value;
cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').as('page1value');
cy.log(page1value) //comes as undefined
```

It would be great if someone could tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Cypress Commands are executed asynchon. You do not know when page1value will be set and thus calling `cy.log()` after the `get` of course must log `undefined`. Please see if the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317965/compare-two-values-and-make-decision-in-cypress fits your needs. If you only want to compare both values, you can write `expect(val1).to.eq(val2)` within he should callback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cypress commands are pushed (enqueued) into a queue (called the Command queue --- which is basically an array), and then executed serially (one after another), and asynchronously.

While your `cy.log()` will be executed asynchronously, too, after the previous command, the value you pass to it (`page1value`) is passed/evaluated synchronously, at the time you push the command to the queue (which is evaluated at the time the callback passed to `it()` is called --- at the beginning of the test).

This is just regular JavaScript behavior, and has nothing to do with Cypress. All the commands `cy.*` are just methods (functions) on the `cy` object, and they're called immediately. What is not called (executed) immediately, is the logic that each command does (e.g. query the DOM for the selector you supply to `cy.get()`, log to Command log when you call `cy.log('string')`, etc.).

Thus, in your 2nd example:

1. You declare `page1value`.
2. You then immediately enqueue commands `cy.get()`, `cy.invoke`, `cy.then()`.
3. And you also immediately enqueue `cy.log`, to which you pass `page1value` (which at this time is still `undefined`).
4. After all commands are enqueued, they start to execute, from top to bottom. When the `cy.then` command takes turn to execute, the `page1value` variable is assigned, but it's no longer used (read) anywhere for the rest of the test (recall that you've already read it when you passed it to the `cy.log` command in the previous step).

Thus, what you want to do instead, is:

```
cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
  cy.log(text);
});
```

In your 3rd example, if you alias something, you need to access that value using another command (remember, everything is asynchronous, so you can't access values that are set asynchronously, in a synchronous manner as you're doing), in this case `cy.get('@aliasName')`:

```
cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').as('page1value');
cy.get('@page1value').then( value => {
  cy.log(value);
});
```

Note that the above explanations are slightly inaccurate and inexhaustive (there are more things going on behind the scenes), for the sake of simplicity. But as an intro to how things work, they should do.

Anyway, you should definitely read [Introduction to Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Cypress-Can-Be-Simple-Sometimes).

You may also take a look at my older answers that touch on related concepts:

- [How to use a variable as a parameter in an API call in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757793/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-parameter-in-an-api-call-in-cypress/58764071#58764071)
- [In Cypress when to use Custom Command vs Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680757/in-cypress-when-to-use-custom-command-vs-task/58680884#58680884)

Comment: Thanks @dwelle for the detailed explanation

Comment: will this work if you change page in meantime? in any case its already ugly enough solution to clutter code with promise just for one variable