# Cypress - store a value to be accessed later

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a test where I need to get the href of a link, and store it to later in the test access it.

It works fine if I write two different tests: one to get the href and another to access the href. But if I do it all in the same test, it doesn't work, why?

```js
// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('getInvitationLink', () => {
  cy.get('a.invitation-link')
    .should('have.attr', 'href')
    .then((href) => {
      assert.isOk(href, 'invitation is found')
      return cy.wrap(href)
    })
})
```

```js
// invitation.spec.js - working

let invitationLink

it('get the invitation link', () => {
  cy.visit('/')

  cy.getInvitationLink().then(href => {
    invitationLink = href
  })

  // assert other stuff on the page...
})

it('access the invitation link', () => {
  cy.visit(invitationLink) // it works!
})
```

```js
// invitation.spec.js - not working

let invitationLink

it('get the invitation link and access it', () => {
  cy.visit('/')


  cy.getInvitationLink().then(href => {
    invitationLink = href
  })

  // assert other stuff on the page...

  cy.visit(invitationLink) // it doesn't work! invitationLink is undefined

})
```

Answer (score 1):

`invitationLink` is defined within the context of a promise. Try moving the `cy.visit` command inside the `.then`:

```
// invitation.spec.js - not working

let invitationLink;

it('get the invitation link and access it', () => {
  cy.visit('/');


  cy.getInvitationLink().then(href => {
    invitationLink = href;
    cy.visit(invitationLink);
    // assert other stuff on the page...

  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense @colefner. If I visit the invitationLink then the page is different and I can't assert other stuff on the page. The order must be this: get the link, do other stuff, visit the link.

Comment: Okay. Then make your assertions on the current page before visiting the new page. The invitationLink isn't defined yet because of the way Cypress executes its commands (async). You are async executing the command and then sync trying to access the result. This link does a better job of explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341731/use-a-value-globally-in-a-test-in-cypress

Comment: Thanks @colefner. Asserting everything before visiting the link is what I'm already doing. So the difference is that I need to do it inside .then(). Roger.

Answer (score 0):

If it just to store and use the value, then create a property like this

```
const asyncLocalStorage = {
    setItem: async function (key, value) {

        return localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    },
    getItem: async function (key) {

        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
};
```

Then set the value as

```
asyncLocalStorage.setItem('storedName', name)
```

and get the value as

```
asyncLocalStorage.getItem('storedName').then((storedName) => {})
```

or just

```
  const name = asyncLocalStorage.getItem('storedName')
```

Comment: using localstorage seems too much for something as simple as accessing a variable. And besides that, I would still have the same issue. @colefner answer was the best so far.

Comment: you can store the variables in cookies if you want a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not waiting that the Promise is resolved before using the invitationLink.

```js
//let invitationLink

it('get the invitation link and access it', () => {
  cy.visit('/')

  cy.getInvitationLink().then(href => {
    const invitationLink = href
    cy.visit(invitationLink) // here is ok
    
    // I can store it for future use
    cy.wrap(invitationLink).as("invitationLink")
  })

  // this is executed before the invitationLink is set
  // cy.visit(invitationLink) // it doesn't work! invitationLink is undefined

  // using the alia... NOT SURE IT WORKS
  cy.wait("@invitationLink").then(invitationLink => cy.visit(invitationLink))

})
```

Don't use local variables (test can run in parallel), [use aliases if you need](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context).
I put it as example but I don't know if the .wait works here (it works for HTTP requests, check cy.intercept()).