# cypress: variable scope outside the then block. I am facing issue

Tags: variables, scope, cypress

I have issue with scope outside the then block. Need help of exerts

```js
  it("Badges Count", () => {
    var totalBadges
    cy.get("div:nth-child(4) > span.quick-stat-figure").then($el => {
      cy.get("div.profile-quick-stats > div:nth-child(4)").click();
        totalBadges = $el.get(0).textContent;
      cy.log("Total Badges", totalBadges); // scope is working here       
  });

  cy.log("Badeges", totalBadges)  // scope is not working here
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a value globally in a test in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341731/use-a-value-globally-in-a-test-in-cypress)

Answer (score 3):

In cases such as these I like to use **aliases**.

Simply wrap() your value, whatever it is, and save it with an alias, then get() and use it wherever you need.

Based on your example it should look something like this:

```
it("Badges Count", () => {
    // var totalBadges - you don't need this anymore
    cy.get("div:nth-child(4) > span.quick-stat-figure").then($el => {
      cy.get("div.profile-quick-stats > div:nth-child(4)").click();
      let totalBadges = $el.get(0).textContent;
      cy.wrap(totalBadges).as('totalBadges'); 
      // this is now accessible globally via get('@totalBadges')         
  });

  cy.get('@totalBadges').then((myBadges) => {
    cy.log("Badeges :"+ myBadges)  // should work just fine
  }
  
});
```

I know it might not look very intuitive, but working with Cypress you will rarely ever need to use variables.

You can check out the Cypress documentation on aliases [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html).