# how extract div text to use later in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

I need to get a string on my page to use later in my Cypress test.
This string is in a flow shared between other tests.
Cypress doesn't allow me to get this string except by using `.then()`
The problem here is that `.then()` works like a promise and I haven't found a way to deal with it

I tried to:

- declare a global variable
- declare an alias
- return a value from within the `.then()` function

Nothing worked.
I think this is a very basic problem with programming. This should allow me to make reusable functions and improve code readability.

Has anyone already solved this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a value globally in a test in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341731/use-a-value-globally-in-a-test-in-cypress)

Comment: Can you also show us your code?